# How to redirect input in Windows CMD without trailing empty inputs?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, io-redirection

I have a program that can be executed through the windows console, will prompt the user for number corresponding to an action (I want to input 3, which corresponds to "Send Script"), and will then prompt the user for another number that tells it which script to send. I have attempted creating a file (in.txt) with the contents:

```
3
3
```

and sending the command `program.exe < in.txt` . However, when this runs, after it inputs both of the values and the correct script starts running, it continues to send values to the program creating constant `Press 0 for help` messages clogging up the output. How can I send just the 2 values I want to send and terminate the input stream after?

A more concrete example of what I am looking for would be way to execute a batch file that consists of

```
pause
pause
pause
pause
pause
```

where I call it by redirecting an input file consisting of 2 inputs to it (`5pause.bat < input.txt`), and the output would be that 2 of the pauses have been passed, but 3 have not.

Comment: Please try to reword your question and include a [mcve] of the code you're having difficulty with. Currently what you've posted does not make sufficient sense for us to replicate your environment and verify what your issue is.

Comment: I think, you can simulate/recreate the behavior of the EXE with a short batch file: `:loop`, `set /p x=`, `echo/%x%`, `goto :loop`. Both methods `test.bat < in.txt` and `type in.txt | test.bat` give never-ending inputs (for different reasons though). @sjette: you can try the second method with your EXE. Maybe you are lucky (but I doubt)